# How to install any specific version of Tomcat on Mac

Tags: tomcat, server, backend

How to  install any specific version of Tomcat on Mac?

by using brew install tomcat , The latest version of Tomcat is getting installed in in my case 9.0.30 But i want on install tomcat version 8 or 7

Answer (score 1):

You should visit Tomcat web site: http://tomcat.apache.org/ and from there download `zip` file of the version you want:

https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi

https://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi

then extract the zip somewhere, configure tomcat, deploy app and start it with shell script.